# Pentaho ETL from mySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, etl, pentaho

I am trying to understand if Pentaho can help me with this scenario:

We want to do a data migration from database A (mySQL) to GCP cloud storage as raw data and then to database B (mySQL as cloud sql) with transformation. Does Pentaho can integrate with cloud storage?

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Data Integration could do that, but it's out of date with regards to cloud storage, I'm not sure if it would work communicating with GCP, I think it works, but I haven't tried, and Hitachi Vantara (the company that bought the Pentaho suite some years ago) is closing all the support to the open source community.

Some old Pentaho DI developers have forked the project and are actively modernizing and applying some new ideas to the tool: I suggest you try apache-hop (https://hop.apache.org/download/) instead of Pentaho, the project is quite mature, they have clean up old PDI bugs (including the log4j library still present in PDI), and are open to new ideas and reporting bugs, if you are beginning with PDI right now, it would be better to start with an actively supported tool.

Comment: What about Talend / nifi - do they support the interaction with GCP cloud storage?